# I am using PHPCake/cPanel/ HostGator/Win8 OS, How can I search for words/commands within many files at once?

Tags: cpanel, windows

How can I search for a specific string (function name or a variable name) in my files which are in various directories under cPanel file manager?

I am a beginner. So please be extra wordy with your explanation :)

I have seen other state something about grep, but I do not have linux or any special software. If someone could tell me what I need to get started would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Since this question is unclear (cPanel doesn't run under Windows 8, unless being run under a virtual machine - see [this](http://forums.cpanel.net/f205/cpanel-windows-server-2008-r2-387432.html)), I'm marking the question as a duplicate. If the linked question doesn't answer this for you, then please edit the question to indicate how it's different, and it will be reviewed to be reopened.

Comment: Hi Dan. I use cPanel through HostGator. I actually resolved my issue last night, and in case someone is in a similar issue as I was, this is what I did..Install WinSCP and use the command icon to "grep" (Google the commands). It found all of the command lines, specific words that I was looking for inside my files. Such a huge time saver...love, love, love it so far!